# Hadith about Allah's rulings on his servants?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Is this hadith authentic?

Abu Tha’labah Al-Khushani  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him narrated that the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) said, “Allaah has ordained obligations, so do not abandon them, and He has set limits, so do not exceed them, and He has prohibited (certain) things, so do not violate them, and He has left (certain) things (unmentioned) out of mercy to you, and not out of forgetfulness, so do not pursue them.” [At-Tabaraani, Ad-Daaraqutni and al-Bayhaqi]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add to the nice post of brother Zia that this hadith is also quoted in [Jami' al-Ulum wal-Hikam](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=148&bk_no=81&flag=1) جامع العلوم والحكم of ibn Rajab al-Hanbali. This book is including the ahadith of imam an-Nawawi's 40 hadith and completing it to 50 hadiths beside comments on each hadith.

Ibn Rajab said that this hadith has two issue's:
First that the hadith is based on a  narration of (the tabi'iy) Makhool  مكحول from (the sahabi) abi Tha'labah al-Khoshni, but there's no evidence that Makhool ever heard or met abu Tha'labah according scholars like abu Na'im and others!
Secondly that scholars are not in consensus whether this is a hadith marfo' or not.

Ibn Rajab qualified it as hassen because of other narrations which support it like a hadith of abu a-Darda'a compiled by al-Bazzar (in his musnad) and al-Hakim (in his mustadrak)... (my own translation take it carefully!)

> عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ، قال : ما أحل الله في كتابه فهو حلال ، وما حرم فهو حرام ، وما سكت عنه فهو عفو ، فاقبلوا من الله عافيته ، فإن الله لم يكن لينسى شيئا ثم تلا هذه الآية : وما كان ربك نسيا [ مريم : 64 ]
>
> ...the Messenger of Allah said: 
> What Allah made halal in his book is halal, and what HE made haram is haram, And what ever He left unmentioned is a mercy (to you), so accept from Allah HIS mercy, as Allah is not forgetting any thing and he recited the verse "And never is your Lord forgetful -" ([19:64](http://legacy.quran.com/19/64))

Which has also been compiled by at-Tabarni and a-Daraqotni on the authorithy of abu a-Darda' with a similar statement as the one of abu Tha'labah ending with: " رحمة من الله فاقبلوها mercy from Allah so accept it" with a weak sanad.

Also [at-Thrimdihi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/24/7) and [ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1334930) have compilled a hadith with a similar meaning on the authority of Salman al-Farisi and [abu Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/28/65) on the authority of ibn 'Abbas. At-Thirmidhi qualified his narration as gharib.

So it is a hadith which is only hassan by support of other narrations, but the content covers the four rulings Allah gave us: orders of Allah, what Allah made haram, the hodod (limits) Allah defined, and what is unmentioned.

Answer (score 3):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

> **عن أبي ثعلبة الخشني جرثوم بن ناشر رضي الله عنه ، عن رسول الله صلي الله
>   عليه وسلم ، قال : (إن الله تعالى فرض فرائض فلا تضيعوها ، وحد حدودًا
>   فلا تعتدوها ، وحرم أشياء فلا تنتهكوها ، وسكت عن أشياء رحمة لكم غير
>   نسيان فلا تبحثوا عنها )**. حديث حسن ، رواه الدارقطني [(في سننه) 4/ 184 ]
>   ، وغيره
>   Some more references i found [somewhere](http://afaqattaiseer.net/vb/showthread.php?t=239#.V9mV2Zh97IU) written while searching:
>   البيهقيُّ (10|12 - 13)
>   وأبو بكرٍ الذكوانيُّ في (اثنا عشرَ مجلسًا) (ق12|1) وابنُ السماكِ في
>   (حديثـِهِ) (2|12|2) والخطيبُ البَغداديُّ في (الفقيهُ والمتفقِّهُ)
>   (ق160|2) ومحمـَّدُ بنُ محمَّدٍ أبو الفتوحِ الطَّائيُّ في (الأربعينَ)
>   (ق31|2 حديث 16) وابنُ بطَّةَ في (الإبانة) (2|126|1)

This hadees is said to be zaeef(muntaqa and mouqouf to be specific) by many scholars for example:

> **الذهبي** قال : " موقوف و منقطع، لم يلق مكحول أبا ثعلبة" ... المهذب [
>   8/3976 ] . **ابن حجر العسقلاني** : " رجاله ثقات إلا أنه منقطع "...المطالب
>   العالية [ 3/271 ] . **الألباني** :" منقطع...حسن لغيره "

**There are no weak narrators in its chain, but there are some issues in the chain**. Its chain is broken, And is not complete. And there is another technical issue. This hadees has some other chains too. Some scholars like ibn-al-Qayyam and al-nouvi are said to consider this hadees acceptable.

**Although its chain is not complete, but its meanings are totally acceptable and their is nothing disputable in them. They indeed are great words, And because of its multiple chains, and many scholars narrating it in their books(Especially some in their sahih collections, which mean they considered it sahih), and the grammar in this hadees is also seems from holy prophet, we can consider this hadith hasan lighairihi.**

For details you can try to read [this](http://www.alhawali.com/popups/print_window.aspx?article_no=2031&type=3&expand=1). And a good discussion about its authenticity and its meanings and acceptibility etc [here](http://afaqattaiseer.net/vb/showthread.php?t=239#.V9mV2Zh97IU).

### Allah knows best